# Electric Field Homework Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electric-fields

Can a charged particle move through an electric field that exerts no force on it?

Comment: Yes, a zero-valued field is still a field. However, this might not be what teacher means. Is there some context?

Comment: Hint: state all three of Newton's laws, just to remind yourself.

Comment: @ Blackbody Blacklight - I am in my college physics textbook and the question has two parts.  I was able to answer the first part, but my original question which you replied to was the second part.  The whole question asks: Can a charged particle move through a magnetic field that exerts no force on it? How? Could it move through an electric field that exerts no force on it? I was able to complete the magnetism part of the question, but I am currently stooped on the electric field portion. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible when $\vec{E} \neq 0$, by definition of the electric field. Given any non-zero $\vec{E}$ and $q$, the *electric* force experienced will be $\vec{F} = q\vec{E}$

Of course, you can consider specific regions where $\vec{E}=0$, i.e. between 2 equal charges.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a very big help and a great explanation!